# Getting RFC function module parameters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sap-dotnet-connector

I am currently using the SAP .NET Connector 3.0 in C# and I want to get the parameters like Import, Export and Table from a given function module.

Is there any way in C# while using the SAP .NET Connector to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to a function module's interface definition, the functionality to query and interpret this RFC meta data from a SAP system is already contained in the connector library.

As an entry point for NCo 3.0, have a look into its official API documentation ***NCo30APIDocumentation.chm*** at class `RfcFunctionMetadata` and loop over its Items. You can get the `RfcFunctionMetadata` object for a specific ABAP function module from method `RfcRepository.GetFunctionMetadata(string functionName)`.

Comment: I have tried now to acces the parameters as you can see by this code: `RfcFunctionMetadata x;` `x = dest.Repository.GetFunctionMetadata("RFC_READ_TABLE");` But how do I get the import, export, changing and tables parameters out of the variable x?

Comment: As said: loop over its Items. The property `ParameterCount` tells you how many parameters this function has. Each indexed `Item` property then represents one of the function interface's import, export, changing and tables parameters, i.e. objects of class `RfcParameterMetadata`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer now I understand. I have one more question because maybe you know the answer, are you able to get the data of a table with `RfcRepository.GetTableMetadata(string tableName)`, because when I try it out I get the error _SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: "cannot find TABLE specified by T247"_

Comment: Yes, this should work if the table with the specified name exists in the Data Dictionary of the ABAP backend and your used user ID has also the required RFC authorizations for querying this meta data. For example, use table name _KNA1_ for testing the query.

Comment: When I try to execute the code with a table that exists in the database i get the error: _SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: "cannot find TABLE specified by T247"_. The weird thing is when I try something random as a tablename I get a different error: _SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: "metadata for TableOnly TEST123 not available: NOT_FOUND: No active nametab exists for TEST123_.

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51516818/7337102

Answer (score 1):

The most official and efficient way is to call the function `RFC_METADATA_GET`. It's explained in the [SAP note 1456826 - Reduction in roundtrips with SAP Connectors](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1456826/E)