# 2 errors when trying to use RFCDestination.Repository.GetTableMetadata(string tablename)

Tags: c#, .net, sap-dotnet-connector

I know that you can get the data of a table in a SAP Server with the function `RFCDestination.Repository.GetTableMetadata(string tablename)`. Unfortunately I get an error when I try to execute the command. The weird thing is when I give a exisiting table I get a different error when I try something random as a tablename.

Existing table:

```
var x = dest.Repository.GetTableMetadata("TFTIT");
```

Error:

> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: "cannot find TABLE specified by TFTIT"

Random tablename:

```
var x = dest.Repository.GetTableMetadata("Test123");
```

Error:

> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: "metadata for TableOnly TEST123 not available: NOT_FOUND: No active nametab exists for TEST123"

I know there is a way to get the data of a table with the help of a function module but I need to use the GetTableMetadata function.

Answer (score 2):

One cannot do so much wrong when calling `RfcRepository.GetTableMetadata(string)`. Does your used user ID has the required RFC authorizations for repository queries as listed in SAP note [460089](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/460089) (scenario 3)? If yes, this is maybe a bug in the NCo3 library or even in the ABAP backend. Do you use NCo's latest patch level? This is currently NCo 3.0.20.
If not, try updating the library first.
Otherwise I recommend to create an SAP support ticket for the first error message. The second error is normal when the specified table name does not exist.

Alternatively you may also try what happens if calling `RfcRepository.GetStructureMetadata(string)` for this table instead. The meta data for tables and structures is quite similar and the same remote function modules are used for the DDIC queries. Maybe this works. However, I think in the first place `RfcRepository.GetTableMetadata(string)` should work here.

I hope this helps.