# How to get parameters of RFC module in node-rfc?

Tags: node.js, saprfc, function-module

I want to introspect input parameters (and maybe output as well) of a RFC given it's name.

I found methods `RfcGetParameterCount` and `RfcGetParameterDescByIndex` which have been used by the node-rfc library itself. But I am not able to figure out how to call these methods using `client.invoke()` or any other way.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rfc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting RFC Function Module Parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473491/getting-rfc-function-module-parameters-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Suncatcher the above link for C# provides RfcRepository.GetFunctionMetadata as the solution. I could not find anything like that for node-rfc.

Comment: I meant [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51474960/911419) which suggests module `RFC_METADATA_GET` which can be called form node-rfc as well

Comment: Yes, that works same as RFC_GET_FUNCTION_INTERFACE in answer below.

Comment: Not the same, it is much more feature-rich, did you ever tried it? It allows fetching primitive types of structured parameters without RTTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RFC_GET_FUNCTION_INTERFACE` returns the parameters of a given RFC.

Comment: This is working after passing the RFC name in FUNCNAME parameter. Now how do I differentiate between input and output parameters from the list of parameters returned ?

Comment: @matpadikar https://imgur.com/a/lHUUdFf. `PARAMCLASS` where I means Importing (Input), E means Exporting (Output), T means Table (usually output but can be input as well)

Comment: Tables (T) in a RFC can be seen as changing parameters (content may or may not be modified by the RFC). You need to understand the specific RFC to understand what it does. They are obsolete but of course exists in many RFC:s. 

Note that an import or export parameter also can be a table!

Comment: Mikael, @Suncatcher For parameters which are complex/structure/EXID=u , how to get the details of that parameter i.e get parameters inside that parameter ?

Comment: `RFC_GET_STRUCTURE_DEFINITION`. You may also need `RFC_GET_NAMETAB`.

Comment: complex parameters have no defaults, only primitive types has defined initial values (=defaults). The initial value of structured types [is produced](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abeninitial_value_glosry.htm) from the initial values of the individual components. To get the type of the components of the structured parameter you should take its type from `TABNAME` field and analyze it with RTTS, and this is out of the scope of this question

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you should call the function module **`RFC_METADATA_GET`** which is the standard way used by SAP official RFC Client libraries, rather than `RFC_GET_FUNCTION_INTERFACE`, which is older (now, it's currently still used internally by `RFC_METADATA_GET` but might not evolve with future releases).

Source in external link: https://answers.sap.com/answers/13891692/view.html (useful information about the internal logic of `RFC_METADATA_GET` and `RFC_GET_FUNCTION_INTERFACE`, by an SAP employee)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this new `rfmcall` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfmcall